# Image tag in flexbox causes overflow

Tags: css, svg, flexbox, tailwind-css, scaling

I'm working with tailwind and try to create a quartered flexbox inside a container with fixed height.

The flexbox should not overflow that fixed height. It works just fine until I add an `img`-element. Then the flexbox grows above the fixed height of the container. This just happens with `img`-elements. Even if I set their height to 1% it causes the flexbox to overflow. If i limit the width of the image element itself, I can counteract the problem. But I want the image to be limited to 100% width/100% height of the parent element (and scaled with preserving aspect ratio).

I've also read that image elements and flexbox have some strange behavior. The recommended solution was to put the image element inside another div container. But that either causes problems with vector images or leads to the same problem with overflow of the flexbox.

```css
.icon {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

.icon > img {
  height: 25%;
  width: auto;
}

.line-red {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.line-green {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.line-blue {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.line-orange {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}

.line-purple {
  outline: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="h-screen"> <!-- Demonstration purpose only -->
  <div class="h-3/4 w-3/4 overflow-auto line-red" style="min-height: 75%;"> <!-- Demonstration purpose only -->
    <div class="flex flex-col align-center h-full">
      <div class="text-center">Title</div>
      <div class="flex flex-wrap self-center h-full w-3/4">
          
        <div class="w-full h-1/4 line-green">
          <div class="icon">
            Box 1
          </div>
        </div>    
          
        <div class="w-full h-1/4 line-blue">
          <div class="icon">
            Box 2
          </div>
        </div> 
          
        <div class="w-full h-1/4 line-orange">
          <div class="icon">
             <img src="https://svgur.com/i/kDQ.svg" />
          </div>
        </div> 
          
        <div class="w-full h-1/4 line-purple">
          <div class="icon">
            Box 4
          </div>
        </div> 
    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You could insert the image / icon with the pseudo element `:before` or `:after`, changing the class of your box. This does not cause the overflow. This solution may not work for you depending on your purpose, but it may be a solution. `<div class="w-full h-1/4 line-orange"><div class="icon-box3"></div></div>` .icon-`box3:before { background-image: url("https://svgur.com/i/kDQ.svg"); background-size: 20px; display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px;  content:""; }`

Comment: @Snorlax thanks. That will be the solution/workaround I'll use for now. As you've said it doesn't work in all scenarios. So I hope we'll find a more suitable solution.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm tagging you since you were one of the users who voted for a close. This question has now rotten in review queue longer than it has actually been open. I've fixed the initial "problem" (which IMO didn't need a close but rather just a friendly hint) 15 minutes after your complaint. The question being closed for so long has probably slimmed the chance of getting an actual answer since nobody bothers about a closed question. It now has 2 reopen votes and needs one more. May you be so kind to vote for a reopen?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set "overflow: hidden" to the grandparent container.  You would expect this to cause the image to be cut off but that won't happen.  The image will shrink.  img behavior in flexboxes is bizarre.  They screwed it up bigtime.  I came upon this solution after lengthy trial and error.

```
<div class="w-full h-1/4 line-orange" style="overflow:hidden">
```